# How to compile an application using libcurl with gcc on mingw

Tags: c, curl, gcc

I am trying to compile a C file containing this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
    CURL * myHandle;
    CURLcode result; // We’ll store the result of CURL’s webpage retrieval, for simple error checking.
    myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;
    // Notice the lack of major error checking, for brevity
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
    result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
    curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle ); 
    printf("LibCurl rules!\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

,

Well when I try to compile :

```
gcc url.c -lcurl
```

I get the following errors:

```
F:\MinGW\home>gcc url.c -lcurl
C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF7doFN.o:url.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF7doFN.o:url.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF7doFN.o:url.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF7doFN.o:url.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF7doFN.o:url.c:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I downloaded  [this distribution](https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w32/curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32.zip)
and copied all files to bin, include , and lib folder.

What am I missing?

**Update**

---

Well I fixed the problem by using `-lcurldll`.

In my lib folder I have both `libcurl.a` and `libcurldll.a`.

Why linking with `libcurl.a` can't compile but with `libcurldll.a` it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the lib name by:
readelf -d [LIB_PATH]

That would solve you the problem.

Comment: @
 K. Orel,thanks I solved my problem, please read the update.

Comment: @K .Orel, please join our [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112581/c-c-windows-api)